# Reduction axis 1 is empty in shape [x,0]

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I'm trying to train the SVHN (street view house numbers) dataset for object-detection in tensorflow (to do some basic OCR on numbers).
So far I have successfully followed the pet-training example from the object-detection-tensorflow guides.
When I train the network based on the sample faster_rcnn_resnet101.config, after a few dozen steps I get:

```
    INFO:tensorflow:Error reported to Coordinator: 
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError'>, 
Reduction axis 1 is empty in shape [3,0]
[[Node: Loss/RPNLoss/Match/cond/ArgMax_1 = ArgMax[T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]
(Loss/RPNLoss/Match/cond/ArgMax/Switch:1, 
Loss/RPNLoss/Match/cond/ArgMax_1/dimension)]]
```

I have no clue what to change or improve.
Has someone seen this before? 
What is going wrong here? 
Is it simply a wrong config-setting?
The only parameter I changed (besides path-info) is num_classes: 10 (10 digits)

Thanks for any hints.

My label-map looks like this:

```
item {
  id: 0
  name: 'none_of_the_above'
}

item {
  id: 1
  name: '1'
}

item {
  id: 2
  name: '2'
}
... with id: 10 being '0'
```

As supposed here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md
I used the pretrained COCO-model faster_rcnn_resnet101 and also the config-file from that: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/samples/configs/faster_rcnn_resnet101_pets.config
The only things I adapted are the paths and:

```
faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 11
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 64
        max_dimension: 900
      }
    }
```

Due to the fact that the images from SVHN are rather small, I adapted the dimensions here and removed all images that are smaller than 64px in height or width.
I didn't pay attention to clear the training-directory until now. But I tried now and the same error occurs.
I'm currently trying with the pretrained inception-model, maybe this works out.

Comment: Can you also provide a link to your label map?

Comment: Added label-map to question.

Comment: That looks fine to my eye... maybe also provide the full config file just for context?  Did you make sure to clear the training directory before relaunching training?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jonathan, for bothering. I added the information.

Comment: Did you fix the problem? I have the same trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what caused your error but you shouldn't use the index 0 in your label map as it's the placeholder index. All indices should start at 1.

See: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1696

Answer (score 0):

This happens when using the `ArgMaxMatcher` class when the number of proposal is 0.

If made a PR that fixes the issue here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/1986

Comment: Thanks Thibaut for your help. But as far as I can see, I'm not using the ArgMaxMatcher.

Answer (score 0):

As the problem vanished, when I'm doing the training correctly, I will post this solution ... might be, that others are as "dumb" as me.
As proposed in the pets-tutorial, I downloaded a pretrained model.
But I set the path to the training-directory to the same directory where the downloaded pretrained model was.
I think this caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set param "pad_to_max_dimension" = true in section "keep_aspect_ratio_resizer". Its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Your image size from dataset is not match with size of model that you used for training.
Ex: If you used mode mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28 then your image size of dataset must be in range[800: 1365]