# Reduction axis 1 is empty in shape [9,0]

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm trying to train a custom object detection model using faster_rcnn_resnet101 model as base and it's checkpoint. But I've been hitting the same issue on 2 different data sets.

These are the config file for the training session
[pipeline.config](https://gist.github.com/TopHatCroat/a33ea7fa0020ce48d7f0842a546c681f)

And I'm converting the data set to the TFRecord format with this script
[tf_record.py](https://gist.github.com/TopHatCroat/768cd06704d21e8a22a1b155d3ff8872)

After running this command
`python object_detection/train.py --logtostderr --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG} --train_dir=${PATH_TO_TRAIN_DIR}`

This is the final output

`InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Reduction axis 1 is empty in shape [9,0]
         [[Node: Loss/RPNLoss/Match/cond/ArgMax_1 = ArgMax[T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, output_type=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](Loss/RPNLoss/Match/cond/Shape_1/Switch:1, Loss/RPNLoss/Match/cond/ArgMax_1/dimension)]]`

[The full stack trace is here](https://gist.github.com/TopHatCroat/38302cc7fe31ab994d688d3623d2c5df)

There has been a similar issue posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44995679/reduction-axis-1-is-empty-in-shape-x-0), but the solution of the author has not helped. <sub>Or am I extra "dumb" and not seing the obvious error</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a comment, but since I have <50 rep and something to say...

I'm running into the same problem with a RCNN architecture. I think this might be due to a mismatch between data types in the model. My error: `ArgMax[T=DT_FLOAT, Tidx=DT_INT32, output_type=DT_INT64, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]`

If you've figured this out, please let us know. Otherwise, let me know what you think about mismatched data types. I'm going to experiment later, when I have time.